# Ckeditor : How can i make few tags like h3 , h4 , h5 non editable in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

Ckeditor : How can i make few tags like h3 , h4 , h5 non editable in ckeditor

open to js solution or css any will do

Answer (score 9):

In config.js, use the following code to define which elements you want to allow in CKEditor (I removed h1) :

```
config.format_tags = 'p;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;pre;address;div'
```

Answer (score 2):

The [**protectedSource**](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.protectedSource) configuration setting is the setting of choice for that.

> **{Array}  CKEDITOR.config.protectedSource**
>
> List of regular expressions to be executed over the input HTML, indicating code that must stay untouched.

I'm no expert on regular expressions but something like this should do the trick:

```
config.protectedSource.push(/[^<]*(<h1>([^<]+)<\/h1>)/g);
```

you may have to play around with it a bit. Caveat: The regex in that form will catch only `<h1>...</h1>` tags, not for example deviations like `< h1 >...< /h1>`.

Comment: Question: if I enable the button to see the source (HTML), can I also prevent a user from making edits?

Comment: @Upper Stage: Good question. I don't know. I'll try out later if I find the time.

Comment: But it doesnt shows the text between h1 tag in the editor

Ishould be able to see it in the editor but not update it

Comment: Indeed, this is not what I expected. When using this option, the editor hides the protected portions of the text. My intention was to let them visible, but not available for the user to modify :(

Answer (score 2):

You can add attribute contenteditable=false to the tag.
E.g.

```
ckeditor.insertHtml('<h1 contenteditable="false">Not editable text</h1>');
```

Comment: This prevents the user from editing the contents of the tag, but it does not prevent the user to delete the whole element altogether by pressing backspace.